# How to handle background music while playing muted video in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, kotlin, android-audiomanager

I have a Flutter app. On opening the app, the app will play a muted video, till here it's perfectly fine. But when I play music in Spotify in the background, and then I try to open my Flutter app, Spotify pauses the background music. So all I want is, to keep Spotify playing music in background while the video in my app keeps playing muted. And when I try to unmute the video in my app, the Spotify music must pause.

```
videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.asset(ConstantAssets.dummyVideo3)
    ..addListener(() {})
    ..setLooping(true)
    ..initialize().then((value){
      videoPlayerController.play();
      videoPlayerController.setVolume(0);
    });
```

So, the concept is like "Playing video Instagram" while listening to Spotify in the background. Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Nothing for this yet?

Comment: looking for this as well

Comment: I also looking for the same

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Set mixWithOthers to true, like this:

```
VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(
        file,
        videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(
          mixWithOthers: true,
        ),
      );
```

or like this:

```
VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
          uri,
          videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(
            mixWithOthers: true,
          ),
        );
```

More info here:
[Videos without audio pauses music and can be stopped by the system](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30438#issuecomment-892613777)